# angular promises and service

Tags: angularjs, promise

I just can't get my head around promises.
Conceptually I get what they're doing I just don't know how to write it (or, at least, debug it).

MyController.js

```
(function() {
    angular.module('WizmoApp').controller('StoreController', storeController);
    storeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$window', 'MyService', 'toastr'];
    function storeController($scope, $http, $q, $window, MyService, toastr) {

    StoreService.getStores().then(
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        function(response) {
            toastr.error(response);
        });
    }
})();
```

As far as I can tell, that is the format for a promise.

MyService.js

```
(function() {
    angular
    .module('WizmoApp')
    .service('StoreService', storeService);
    storeService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'ngAuthSettings'];

    function storeService($http, $q, ngAuthSettings) {

        this.getStores = function() {
            $.getJSON('Content/data/Stores.json', function (json) {
                            return json;
            });
    };
})();
```

The error I get is

> StoreService.getStores(...).then is not a function

Comment: Use $http to make $http requests and return promises. Not JQuery. Read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: The reason I'm using a service is so I can flip between API and local json. Using $http in my controller forces a choice I want to leave open.

Comment: You can use $http in your service, I believe what JB Nizet is referring to is your use of `$.getJSON` there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise resolver so that you can invoke the .then() function on it. For example:

```
this.getStores = function() {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.getJSON('Content/data/Stores.json', function (json) {
        resolve(json);
    });
  });
}
```

Or the older CommonJS notation:

```
this.getStores = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $.getJSON('Content/data/Stores.json', function (json) {
      deferred.resolve(json);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Remember to inject $q into your StoreService. See here for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: OK, that seems to work, though I think I still don't have it right because I've got a nested promise now. I will show the context of what I'm doing with the service (which I perhaps should have done before, but it would have complicated things).

Answer (score 1):

Without testing yet in plunker, your service is injected as 'MyService' not 'StoreService', so it should look like:

storeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$window', 'StoreService', 'toastr'];
function storeController($scope, $http, $q, $window, StoreService, toastr) {

```
StoreService.getStores().then(
```

Comment: Yes. It's actually called StoreService.

Comment: in your $inject you have MyService, it should be StoreService: storeController.$inject ... I updated my answer. Let me know

Comment: Yes, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not think this was relevant - I thought it would just complicate my question but it seems to be closely tied. The purpose of the service is to allow me to flip back and forth between "canned" json data and live api data.

See the dataSource variable used in the switch:

storeController.js

```
StoreService.getStores().then(function(response) {
    vm.stores = response.data;
}, function(response) {
    toastr.error(response);
 });
```

storeService.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('WizmoApp')
        .service('StoreService', storeService);

    storeService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'ngAuthSettings'];

    function storeService($http, $q, ngAuthSettings) {

       var dataSource = 'api';// local or api

        this.getStores = function() {

            return $q (function(resolve, reject) {
                switch (dataSource) {
                    case 'api'://staging - live api data
                        $http({
                            method: 'get',
                            url: serviceBase + 'api/Stores'
                        }).then(function(results) {
                            resolve(results.data);
                        });
                        break;

                    default: // dev - local json
                        $.getJSON('Content/data/Stores.json', function (json) {
                            resolve(json);
                        });
                }
            });
        };
```

So, now I've got one promise nested inside the other. It seems to work, I'm just not sure it's efficient.